# How to create the view in android?

Tags: java, android

Can someone tell me how should i create the above view [here](http://www.google.com.sg/imglanding?q=dialog%20box%20android%20example&hl=en&sa=X&tbm=isch&tbnid=6GDKENa7dfWAPM%3a&imgrefurl=http://thedevelopersinfo.com/2009/10/22/email-sending-in-android/&imgurl=http://thedevelopersinfo.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/email.png&w=324&h=481&ei=jjvLTcTdDImYvAONybzeBQ&zoom=1&iact=hc&page=2&tbnh=162&tbnw=109&start=21&ndsp=26&ved=1t:429,r:9,s:21&biw=1366&bih=653) via xml or java coding in android?

This is what i have tried so far... But the view just seems to look too plain without any pictures by the side of each string as shown in the above link? What should i do to get the sort of more professional view?

```
final String [] items = new String []{"Details", "Delete File"};
         AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
         builder.setTitle("File Options");

         builder.setItems(items, new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(arg1 == 0)
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DialogBox.class));
            }
            else
            {
                deleteFile();
            }
        }
        });
        builder.create().show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this code
  This to show the dialog and code for each button,as we do in onCreate.

```
private void showRules() {

    final Dialog ruleDialog = new Dialog(this);
    ruleDialog.setContentView(R.layout.ruledialog);

    Button cancelbtn = (Button)ruleDialog.findViewById(R.id.cancelbtn);
    //cancelbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    cancelbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            ruleDialog.dismiss();

        }
    });

    ruleDialog.setCancelable(true);
    ruleDialog.show();
    //dialog.setTitle("How");
    }
```

This the xml that I have use for it,

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView
   android:id="@+id/dialogHead"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:text="@string/dialogHead"
   android:paddingBottom="20px"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   />
   <Button
   android:id="@+id/cancelbtn"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/ic_cancel"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:paddingRight="3px"
   android:paddingTop="3px"

   /> 

   <ScrollView
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_below="@id/dialogHead"
    >
    <TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/dialogBody"

    />


   </ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: i do not really know how to configure my xml for my own case?? Because i do have much experience in coding xml... Sob.. Could you help me?

Comment: Could you help me get the appropriate xml format? Do i need two textview ,two imageview and two scroll view? Or something else, i'm rather new to xml...

Comment: it is simple just create the xml file inside the res/layout then just copy/peast the above code and call the function

Comment: But it seems your xml does not fit the context of my situation?

Comment: this is just example,can change it as you want

Answer (score 0):

see here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog you can create your own layout and define what ever you'd like.  as for professionalism - thats in the eye of the beholder.

Edit: 
so don't use your string array to set your text.

create a layout that has a TextView ImageView TextView.  use the layout inflator to inflate the view. find the 1st textview and setText("Details") (if you didn't do it statically in the xml)

find the second textview and setText("Delete") (if you didn't do it statically in the xml)

find the image and setImageResource (if you didn't do it statically in the xml)

set the builders view to your layout.

oh and maybe add some buttons with onclick listeners to do your stuff.  or use an alertdialogbuilder.

Comment: @khouw1 i read the link before but i have no idea how to force an imageview beside the string of "Details" and "Delete"?? Sorry i'm rather new in programming..

Comment: @khouw1 so i have to create an xml to do create the view you mention above?

Comment: @khouw1 i still quite get you?